# Receive echo from php (xamarin)

Tags: c#, php, xamarin

I'm writing an app in C# with Xamarin I have created the PHP file, if I test in the browser it works. it echoes back (ok) (error password) (error login)

I don't know how to receive it back in xamarin so I can write a basic validation

php

```
<?php  
require_once('ConnectionInfo.php');  
if(isset($_GET['Username']) && isset($_GET['Password'])){ 

$Username = $_GET['Username']; 
$password = $_GET['Password']; 

    mysql_select_db($database_localhost,$con);   
    $query_search = "SELECT * FROM user where Username = '$Username'";   
    $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());   
    if($query_exec!=null){   
        while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec)) { 
             $password_array = $result_array['Password']; 
        } 
        if($password == $password_array){ 
            echo "OK"; 
        }else{ 
            echo "ERROR PASSWORD"; 
        } 
    }else { 
        echo "ERROR LOGIN"; 
    } 
}else{ 
    echo "ERROR"; 
} 
?>
```

so in c# button event basically

```
if(ok)
{
//go to next page
} else {
//show error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read the output from the php, the code below will do the trick

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();

 byte[] html = client.DownloadData(http://tempuri.com/temp.php);
 UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
 string res = utf.GetString(html);

   if(res == "OK")
   {
      //go to next page
   } else {
      //show error
   }
```